# ある、いる、and いるの in this sentence

Tags: translation, meaning, verbs

> いま どこ に いるの

I found this sentence online while I was trying to better understand the verbs ある and いる and apparently its translates to "Where are you now"

I know what most of the sentence is but I guess I'm having a hard time understanding exactly as to how ある and いる translate and then I found の at the end of いる and I have no idea what this の could mean. 
I understand they usually mean "to have" or "there is" and I'm not sure why but when I see them they always confuse me.

> ex. たべたい ひと が いる

This is the title of a song I found and I want to say it translates as

> There is a person/There are people I want to eat

But I'm not really sure、 and I don't really know why I'm so unsure
since the concept behind ある and いる does seem simple.

apologies if this question as a whole doesn't make much sense

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Difference between ある and いる

Both ある and いる translate to "exist". The main difference is that ある is used for inanimate objects and いる is used for alive/animate things.

So if you want to say "there is a cat", you would say "ねこ が いる". But if you wanted to say "there is a chair", you would say "いす が ある".

## 2. The sentence you mentioned: いま どこ に いるの

**2.1. To understand this, let's first analyse the phrase without the の in the end**

> いま どこ に いる

The translation you pointed out, *"Where are you now?"*, is correct. Why?

- いま means now
- どこ means where
- いる means to exist;
- に is a particle that, when used alongside いる, means the location of the object.

Therefore, this sentence would translate roughly to *"Now where do [you] exist?"*. Note that the "you" is guessed. It could very well be "we", or "him", and such.

That rough translation is the same as "Where are you now?" in better english.

[Learn more about the に particle here](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/verbparticles#part3)

**2.2. Understanding the の in the end**

Don't worry if you get confused with the の particle. It has various meanings, so you have to detect what is its role in each situation. Sometimes it will mean possession, like in "Bob の ほん" (Bob's book). In the end of sentences, though, it will **in general** consist of the **explanatory の particle**. It justs add an explanatory tone to the sentence. The sentence you mentioned is a question, so the の particle in the end emphasizes that the questioner is looking for an explanation.

[Learn more about the explanatory の particle here](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/nounparticles#part5)

## 3. たべたい ひと が いる

<s>You are correct to guess the translation: There is a person/There are people I want to eat.</s>

EDIT: At a first glance this can be translated as *There is a person/There are people I want to eat*, but clearly this is a bit unusual, although still possible, if this is a fictional setting, and the 'thing' speaking is a monster, for example. But this could also be translated as *There is a person/There are people who want(s) to eat.*

(Thanks @Yosh for bringing this up)

## 4. Last words

Both links I suggested above are from the same guide, called **Tae Kim's Guide to Learning Japanese**. I totally recommend it, it is free, [this is the link](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/).

Comment: I would interpret 食べたい人がいる as "there's a person / there are people who want(s) to eat" assuming some context to follow, as wanting to eat people is quite irregular. 会いたい人がいる surely translates to "there's a person (or plural) I want to meet".

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

The `の` at the end of the sentence makes the sentence sounds more natural, it doesn't really have a meaning by itself.

You could, as well, use `か` instead to make it clear that the sentence is a question, either replacing `の` with `か` or using `のか`

So the question `いま どこ に いるの` means `where are we now?`